# SOAP 1.1 and multidimensional Arrays

Tags: arrays, soap, multidimensional-array

Does SOAP 1.1 support multidimensional Arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search through the specification. It states:

> Arrays may be multi-dimensional.

You can read about it at [5.4.2 Arrays](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383522) in the SOAP 1.1 specs.